# Conexão com MySQL no Roundcube

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

[Roundcube](http://roundcube.net/) é um webmail de software livre.

Preciso implementar uma classe em HTML para conexão do Roundcube com banco de dados MySQL.

Tenho um arquivo que fica no skin/larry/template/login.html, a ideia era mudar a pagina de login. Ja ecrevir toda a pagina. Agora não estou entendo como o roundcube ja conexão com o banco de dados. Quais funcões devo usar.

Comment: O que você já fez? Poste aí. Tem alguma dúvida específica? Classe em HTML para conectar com MySQL? Tem certeza?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara, acho que vc está meio confuso.. Não existe "Classe HTML", HTML é uma linguagem de marcação apenas, ela serve pra definir e exibir o site no navegador, para fazer uma conexão com um banco de dados você precisa de uma linguagem de programação, no caso, PHP (a linguagem na qual o RoundCube é feito).

No caso que você citou eles parecem usar uma linguagem de template para renderizar as páginas do sistema, analisado a página que você citou, vi que o form é criado nesse trecho:

```
<roundcube:form name="form" method="post">
<roundcube:object name="loginform" form="form" size="40" submit=true />
</form>
```

Eu não sei qual a linguagem de template que está sendo utilizada, mas dando uma olhada rápida deduzi que esteja chamando este método:

```
protected function login_form($attrib)
```

No arquivo: [program/include/rc_mail_output_html.php](https://github.com/roundcube/roundcubemail/blob/master/program/include/rcmail_output_html.php#L1567)

Resumindo: Você pode usar o HTML acima para poder exibir o form de login num template customizado, agora para customizar o próprio form em si, ou alterar a função que está sendo executada no submit do form já é algo bem mais complicado.

Talvez seja melhor vc procurar uma documentação no site do próprio RoundCube, ou entrar em contato com eles para saber como customizar melhor o seu próprio template.

Comment: Matheus essa chamada do roundcube:form e roundcube:object que não estou conseguindo entender de onde está chamando.